# Animation not working on marker click(Only 1st click)

Tags: android, android-animation, marker

When i click the marker for the 1st time the view suddenly appears on the screen,then i click the marker again the view appears in fade-in animation.
The animation is not working only for 1st marker click.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            final Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fadein);
            animationFadeIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "animation start");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "animation end");
                    profile_details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            profile_details.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: is the initial visibility of profile_details view is GONE?

Comment: i have another button to set visibility to GONE, and yes initial visibility is GONE

Comment: then move the profile_details.setVisibilty(VISIBLE) inside onAnimationStart() and if it blinks at start of animation then setAlpha=0 inside onAnimationStart

Comment: setAlpha to 0 didn't work but adding setVisible(View.Visible) in onAnimationStartWorked, can you just write in answers so i can mark it as correct. Thanks man

Comment: Done already. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just move the profile_details.setVisibilty(VISIBLE) inside onAnimationStart().